# Which functions can be used in Google Earth Engine in Iteration structure ee.List.iterate?

Tags: google-earth-engine

```js
var listA = ee.List(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]);
var listB = ee.List([15, 3, 17, -2, 6]); // sorted: -2 3 6 15 17

var combinedList = listA.zip(listB);
print(combinedList);

var sortedListB = listB.sort();

var iterTime = listA.length();
print(iterTime);
var iterList = ee.List.sequence(0, iterTime);
var sortedListA = ee.List.repeat("0", iterTime);

print(sortedListB);

function iteraFunc(Info, Index)
{
  var originText = listA.get(Index);
  var originTextPos = listA.indexOf(originText);
  var originNum = listB.get(originTextPos);
  var nowTextPos = listB.indexOf(originNum);
  //sortedListA = sortedListA.set(nowTextPos, originText);
  return sortedListA;
}
var m = iterList.iterate(iteraFunc, [0]);

print(m);
```

Like this.
In the iteration ee.List.iterate(), all the data were proceed in GEE server, which meant some commands is disabled like print(), ee.List.set(), etc.
So which command can be used for iterate in GEE server?

Comment: `ee.List.set` is actually a command that runs on the server side, thus it can be run without problems using `ee.List.iterate`. Nonetheless, `print` is a client-side function which will not run properly inside the `ee.List.iterate`.